# Using @Endpoint one or multiple times

Tags: spring, spring-ws

Is there any performance difference between Option 1 & Option 2 mentioned below?

**Option 1**

using one Endpoint file for multiple requests

- First_Second_Endpoint

  ```
   @Endpoint
    public class First_Second_Endpoint 
        {
         @PayloadRoot(localPart = "FirstRequest", namespace = "...")
         @ResponsePayload
         public FirstResponse methodName(@RequestPayload FirstRequest request) {...}

         @PayloadRoot(localPart = "SecondRequest", namespace = "...")
         @ResponsePayload
         public SecondResponse secondMethodName(@RequestPayload SecondRequest request)
         {...}

      }
  ```

---

**Option 2**

using multiple Endpoint file for multiple requests

- First_Endpoint.java

  ```
   @Endpoint
    public class First_Endpoint 
        {
         @PayloadRoot(localPart = "FirstRequest", namespace = "...")
         @ResponsePayload
         public FirstResponse methodName(@RequestPayload FirstRequest request) {...}

      }
  ```
- Second_Endpoint.java

  ```
    @Endpoint
    public class Second_Endpoint 
    {
         @PayloadRoot(localPart = "SecondRequest", namespace = "...")
         @ResponsePayload
         public SecondResponse secondMethodName(@RequestPayload SecondRequest request)
         {...}

      }
  ```

---

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference, because in the end any `@Endpoint` class just registered as a bean in the application. But it isn't important, because these is needed just for further `method scanning` and registration an `endpointMapping` for each method (`AbstractMethodEndpointMapping`):

```
for (Method method : methods) {
    List<T> keys = getLookupKeysForMethod(method);
    for (T key : keys) {
        registerEndpoint(key, new MethodEndpoint(beanName, getApplicationContext(), method));
    }
}
```

As you see it doesn't use the root `@Endpoint` object for this infrastructure, only methods are important to be mapped for SOAP requests.

It doesn't impact to the performance at runtime, because only `AbstractMethodEndpointMapping.endpointMap` is in use:

```
protected MethodEndpoint lookupEndpoint(T key) {
    return endpointMap.get(key);
}
```